# Can class member be initialized with another class member in the initializer list?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, member

Suppose I have class with two members,

```
class App
{
public:
   App() : window(1366, 768, "Title"), drawer(window) {}
private:
   Window window;
   Drawer drawer;
}
```

and the Drawer class has constructor `Drawer(const Window&)`.
Is it valid to initialize the App class member Drawer with the another class member Window, like in this example?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Example), it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, following is valid:

```
class App
{
public:
   App() : window(1366, 768, "Title"), drawer(window) {}
private:
   Window window;
   Drawer drawer;
};
```

Comment: May want to mention that this is brittle code and if the variables get swapped around in the class it may no longer be vaild.

Answer (score 1):

The non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition. So in this particular instance it works as `window` is declared before `drawer` in the definition of `App`.
But if you change the order, this will not work as intended.

But a compiler will warn you about this with appropriate warning level. GCC 8.2 with `-Wall` option issues the following warnings if the order is reversed.

```
#1 with x86-64 gcc 8.2
<source>: In constructor 'App::App()':

<source>:16:14: warning: 'App::window' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
       Window window;
              ^~~~~~

<source>:15:14: warning:   'Drawer App::drawer' [-Wreorder]
       Drawer drawer;
              ^~~~~~

<source>:13:4: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
    App() : window(1366, 768), drawer(window) {}
    ^~~
```

As `drawer` is initialized first, it will not be initialized with the `window` object that has been constructed with the values 1366 and 768.